# migrate from Weblogic to tomcat issue

Tags: java, tomcat, ejb, weblogic, openejb

I am migrating application from WebLogic to Tomcat.

I get to know that Tomcat is unable to process EJB code, which were added into the project while project deployed on WebLogic.

So, that finally reach to use TomEE(1.7.2) Server which help to deal with EJB code.

but while running that project under TomEE Server error appears likewise,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEDataSource cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object
```

My TomEE Server's Server.xml contain following code,

```
<Resource name="abc/myjndiName" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    factory="org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST 
    =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname.com)(PORT = 1111))
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname.com)(PORT = 1111))
     (LOAD_BALANCE = yes))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = hostname.com)))"
      user="XXX" password="XXX"
      maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000" />
```

can anybody fix it ? what's went wrong ?
then it would be an appreciate.

Thanks.

Error's Full-Stack Trace looks likewise,

```
Unexpected exception in EJBComponentFinder.getAnyHome: java.lang.ClassCastException.java.lang.ClassCastException
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(Unknown Source)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(Unknown Source)
    at development.component.util.ObjectFactory.getAnyHome(ObjectFactory.java:457)
    at development.component.util.ObjectFactory.createSiteConfigurationEJB(ObjectFactory.java:322)
    at development.component.ui.ComponentApplicationServlet.loadSiteConfigParameters(ComponentApplicationServlet.java:615)
    at development.component.ui.ComponentApplicationServlet.init(ComponentApplicationServlet.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator$TomEEDataSource cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object
    ... 18 more
```

**-----------------**
**Code Method  : getAnyHome(...)**
**----------------**

```
public EJBHome getAnyHome(Class homeClass)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = ContextLocator.getClientContext();
        try
        {
            Map jndiEJBMap = null;
            synchronized (allClassMaps)
            {
                String compoundKey = clientContext.getSiteName() + "_ejb_jndi_mappings";
                jndiEJBMap = (Map) allClassMaps.get(compoundKey);
                if (jndiEJBMap == null)
                {
                    SiteConfig config;
                    // not cached, retrieve from configuration files and cache
                    if (clientContext.getConfigFilePath() != null &&
                            clientContext.getConfigFilePath().length() > 0)
                    {
                        config = SiteConfigFactory.getInstance().getConfig(clientContext.getSiteName(), clientContext.getConfigFilePath());
                    }
                    else
                        config = SiteConfigFactory.getInstance().getConfig(clientContext.getSiteName());

                    jndiEJBMap = config.getMap("ejb_jndi_mappings");
                    allClassMaps.put(compoundKey, jndiEJBMap);
                }
            }
            String jndiName = (String) jndiEJBMap.get(homeClass.getName());
            if (jndiName == null)
            {
                String msg = "ObjectFactory cannot find tag <mapentry name=\"" + homeClass.getName() + "\"> within tag <map name=\"ejb_jndi_mappings\"> for site (" + clientContext.getSiteName() + "), cannot create EJB.";
                Log.error(msg);
                throw new ConfigurationException(msg);
            }

            Object anyHome = namingContext.lookup(jndiName);
            // Then narrow the reference and return it

            return (EJBHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(anyHome, homeClass); // Here Error Comes
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            String msg = "Unexpected exception in EJBComponentFinder.getAnyHome: " + exc.toString() + ".";
            Log.error(msg, exc);
            throw new EJBException(msg);
        }
    }
```

**-----------------**
**Code Method  : createSiteConfigurationEJB()**
**-----------------**

```
public static SiteConfigurationEJB createSiteConfigurationEJB()
    {
        try
        {
            SiteConfigurationHome home =
                    (SiteConfigurationHome) getInstance().getAnyHome(SiteConfigurationHome.class);
            return home.create();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            String msg = "Unexpected exception in ObjectFactory.createSiteConfigurationEJB: " + exc.toString() + ".";
            Log.error(msg, exc);
            throw new EJBException(msg);
        }
    }
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace of the ClassCastException?

Comment: Hey wero,
I have edited my question and added full stacktrace.

Comment: can you show what your doing in `development.component.util.ObjectFactory.getAnyHome()` and `createSiteConfigurationEJB()`?

Comment: both method code added.